# Vue.js - How to add a event handler to a Bootstrap element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an app where I'm using Bootstrap 5. In this app, I have an [Offcanvas component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/). I need to do some work when this component closes. In an attempt to do this, I wanted to hook into the [`hide.bs.offcanvas` event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#events). My Vue item looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom overlay-offcanvas" tabindex="-1" id="myOffCanvas" ref="myOffCanvas" aria-labelledby="overlayOffCanvasLabel" data-bs-backdrop="false">
      <div class="offcanvas-header bg-secondary text-white">
        <h6 class="offcanvas-title" id="overlayOffCanvasLabel">Hello</h6>
        <button data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">x</button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
         Hello, world
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { Offcanvas } from 'bootstrap';

  export default {
    data() {
      myOffCanvas: null
    },

    methods: {
      onOffcanvasHidden() {
        alert('Good bye!');
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.myOffCanvas = new Offcanvas(this.$refs.myOffCanvas);
    }
  }
</script>
```

How do I call `onOffcanvasHidden` when the offcanvas elements is closed? In other words, how do I wire-up an event handler to the `hide.bs.offcanvas` event from Vue.js?

Comment: Wouldn't you just `myOffcanvas.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', () => { ... })` once you have the ref ready for the element? I got the idea by looking at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#events

Comment: @RoboKozo No. When I add `this.myOffCanvas.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', () => { ... });` after the other line in the `mounted` event, I receive an error that says `this.myOffCanvas.addEventListener is not a function`.

Comment: Try with `this.$refs.myOffCanvas.addEventListener` after your `new Offcanvas` also consider making a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example